# Android ellipsis at a particular position

Tags: android, textview, ellipsis

Is there any possible way to put the ellipsis at a particular position in textView.

**Normal case:** text1 / text2 / text3

**Lengthy text:** lenghtytext1 / leng... / lenghtytext3

As shown above, I want to add the ellipsis(...) before the last '/'. The text is shown in a single textView in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 textViews in a RelativeLayout to achieve this purpose. For example in case of your string below:
Lengthy text: lenghtytext1 / leng... / lenghtytext3

"lenghtytext1 / leng...": is one textView with ellipsize end.

"/ lenghtytext3": is another textView